# why it is 2>&1 and not 2>>&1 to append to a log file

Tags: bash, shell, redirection, stderr, append

I am redirecting STDOUT and STDERR to a single file, always growing,
so I use always use "append" redirection; this is `>>`

my command is `command >> logfile  2>&1`

And it works.

But the STDERR redirection has a single `>`, which I was using to "create" the file, erasing the previous one, as in `command > outlog 2> errlog`

Why it does not erase the log file in this case?

Comment: Welcome to Super User and congrats on an interesting first question!

Comment: The tokens aren't split up the way you think they are. That is, it's not "`>` for redirect to file" and "`&1` for which file to redirect to", it's "`>&` for redirect to file descriptor (which is not the same thing as a file)" and "`1` for which descriptor to redirect to". So it's a completely different operation, and you shouldn't a priori expect to be able to transfer any intuition from `>` or `>>` to `>&`. (This is just a first approximation. In the second approximation, there are some implementation details shared between the three operators, so you *can* transfer some knowledge...)

Comment: @DanielWagner Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 60):

When you redirect something to `&number`, you are not opening a new file at all; you're **reusing an already open file** along with whatever mode it was opened.

The numbers refer to "open file" handles (file descriptors). So there is no technical difference between how `>&` and `>>&` (and indeed `<&`) would work – they all just mean "clone the existing file descriptor using dup()".

That is, `2>&1` indicates that file descriptor #1 (which you previously opened *for appending* using `>>logfile`) is cloned into number #2. And yes, `2<&1` works identically.

Side technical note: Appending vs truncating is not an explicit action done by the shell; it's actually a mode the shell specifies *when opening* the file, and the rest is performed by the OS itself. For example, when you use `>` the shell doesn't *manually* erase the old contents, it just adds O_TRUNC when calling open(). Therefore, when open() isn't called *at all*, the previous mode remains unchanged.

Comment: Is O_TRUNC  something you run into when doing windows programming in C?

Comment: @barlop: Yes; not _exactly_, but quite similar. If you develop on raw Win32 API, the CreateFile() function has TRUNCATE_EXISTING, which means the same thing as POSIX open()'s O_TRUNC, and you have DuplicateHandle() which is like dup(), even if Windows' stdin/stdout are a bit weirder and more special-cased. (If you develop on Mingw, you just get the same POSIX open(). And most higher level I/O libraries, like C stdio or Python io, have modes such as "w" "a" "r+" which directly translate to the same thing.)

Comment: @grawity, your explanation suggests that `command 2>&1 >> logfile` will overwrite the file, which is not the case, could you elaborate that? In my experiment error output went to console and standard output went to the file.

Comment: @Oliv: Does it? You're not using any "overwrite" redirection operator, you're just using the same "duplicate fd" and "append to file".

Comment: Note that "cloning" here is not "aliasing". Once 2>&1 clones fd 1 to fd 2, they're still two independent file descriptors that merely reference the same "open file". Further redirections of fd 1 do not affect fd 2.

Comment: I think what it does is that it first redirects error output to console and then standard output to console. So the order matters.

Comment: Fun fact: `O_APPEND` is a special flag that's separate from just omitting `O_TRUNC`.  It means any write automatically happens at the end of the file, even if *other* writers made the file longer since your last write.   i.e. every `write()` becomes like an atomic combination of `lseek(SEEK_END) + write()`.  You can open a file for overwrite without truncation using for example `dd of=foo conv=notrunc`

Comment: Also, note that order is important... `2>&1 >> logfile` will redirect `stderr` to the terminal, and then subsequently redirect the application's `stdout` to `logfile`.

Answer (score 14):

The sequence `command >> logfile 2>&1` has two redirection stages:

- `command >> logfile` will append to the logfile
- `2>&1` will redirect stderr to stdout (which itself **appends** to the logfile)

So `command >> logfile 2>&1` will not truncate the log file, while `command >>logfile 2>logfile` would.

Comment: What about `command >>logfile 2>>logfile`?

Comment: @Zereges Probably gives an error because you try to open logfile for writing twice. One of the 2 "opens" should fail with an error along the lines of "file already open (or locked) by another process"

Comment: No, files on Unix-like systems are not locked merely by being open. (For that matter, e.g. Linux doesn't support mandatory locking _at all._)

Comment: @Zereges: You'd get 2 separate file descriptors (not duplicates of each other) each with their own file position.  But they're both opened in `O_APPEND` mode, so every write is like an atomic `lseek(SEEK_END) + write()`.  So I think it would Just Work with the same end result as normal `dup2()` but probably slightly less efficient.